# Is it possible to create a class, each instance of which will have different type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

It is more of a theoretical question and does not relate to actual problem.

Considering you have some class:

```
class A():
    pass

a = A()
type(a)
# <class '__main__.A'>
```

Is it possible to implement something like this?

```
from random import randint

class Randomized(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['__qualname__'] += str(randint(0, 99))
        return super(Randomized, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(metaclass=Randomized):
    pass

a = A()
b = A()
# as I was thinking:
type(a)
# <class '__main__.A75'>
type(b)
# <class '__main__.A23'>
```

Example above doesn't work as I expected because it seems that `Randomized.__new__` called only once:

```
a = A()
b = A()
type(a)
# <class '__main__.A66'>
type(b)
# <class '__main__.A66'>
```

Related PEP about metaclasses:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/

Comment: In context of Python, "class" and "type" are synonyms. Thus, tautologically, if an instance would have a different type, it must be an instance of a different class.

Comment: @Amadan I know that but did not realized how to make a question to sound more clear.

Comment: "Is it possible to create a class whose constructor will make objects of different classes?" works — though, I concede that it also gives a hint for the solution :D If you could phrase it that way, you may not have had to ask the question. So, no blame on you, just a clarification for anyone (not necessarily you) who might not realise it.

Comment: "If you could phrase it that way, you may not have had to ask the question." - Exactly :D I was too obsessed with metaclasses to catch a more simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place `__new__` in `A` class to achieve desired behavior. Example:

```
from random import randint


class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        random_cls = type('random_name' + str(randint(0, 99)), (object,), {})
        return random_cls()


a = A()
b = A()
print(type(a))
# <class '__main__.random_name90'>
print(type(b))
# <class '__main__.random_name22'>
```

`__new__` in metaclass is called on class `A` creation but not on creation of it's *instances* as you expected.